# How I can change the whole section background? In which class shoul I use?

Tags: html, css, background

I couldn't figure which class I should use the change this section background color or use an image. If someone could help me it will be nice.
I am using WordPress so this is supposed to be a section in a page, so I don't want to change the body background. thanks!!

```css
/* General */

#nr-1:hover + .bg-1,
#nr-2:hover + .bg-2 {
    opacity: 1;
}

.flexboxcenter {
    display: flex;
    direction: rtl;
    float: right;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: right;
}

.section-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.hover-link {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100000;
}

.hover-link .nav-1 {
    z-index: 10000;
}

.svc-title {
    direction: rtl;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Heebo', serif;
    float: right;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #a2a3a7;
    z-index: 100001;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.add-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
    direction: rtl;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hover-link .nav-1 a {
    right: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Heebo', serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0.7px;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.hover-link .nav-1:hover a {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.hover-link .nav-1 a::after {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 0.25em;
    content: "\f30a";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 900;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.hover-link .nav-1 a:hover {
    color: black !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transform: translate(-20px) !important;
}

.hover-link .nav-1 a:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}


/* Background classes */

.bg-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432821596592-e2c18b78144f?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=3f9c78df0edb464244bbabb04d1797d8') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.bg-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421757295538-9c80958e75b0?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=3628f27cd5768ece147877e2dd792c6c') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="svc-title"> השירותים שאנו מציעים:
    </span>
<section id="section-1">
    <div class="hover-link flexboxcenter">
        <div class="nav-1">
            <a href="#" id="nr-1" class="hvr-underline-from-center"> הדמיות אדריכליות</a>
            <div class="bg-1"></div>
            <br>
            <a href="#" id="nr-2" class="hvr-underline-from-center nr-2">הדמיות פנים</a>
            <div class="bg-2"></div>
            <br>
            <a href="#" id="nr-2" class="hvr-underline-from-center nr-2">הדמיות חוץ</a>
            <div class="bg-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Also it seems to me that I have unused code or unrelevant, if some can help me in that matter also I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You want to use only one `background-image` or `background-color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `<section id="section-1">` for section as I see.

So CSS will be:

```
#section1 {
background-color: #colorhex; 
}
```

For color.

```
#section1 {
background-image: url('imageurl');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center-center;
}
```

For image background.

Hope it will help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just try to add a background to your section ?
Like :

```
.section-1 {
    background: url('https://............');
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Watch the class bg-1 and bg-2 to get more information, at the end of your code ;)